# codename one- unable to launch native android app from codename one

Tags: android, paypal, codenameone

I am trying to launch native android app installed in device from cadename one, and using the code :

```
Display.getInstance().execute("intent:#Intent;action=com.tag.paypalblogdemo;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;S.msg_from_browser=Launched%20from%20Browser");
```

in the native app manifest file :

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.androidsrc.launchfrombrowser" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   </intent-filter>
```

but when I am access it from the device, no action is performed.

Comment: Did you connect your device with a cable and looked thru DDMS? Do you see any issues in the log?